# App crashes when AlertDialog is supposed to open for the second time

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-alertdialog

When I long click a ListView item, it opens an AlertDialog with three buttons. One of them is "Rename" to rename the item etc.

```
longClickAlert.setNegativeButton("Rename", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    renameAlert.setMessage("New name:");
                    renameAlert.setView(input);
                    renameAlert.setPositiveButton("Enter", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            renameLine(externalStoragePath + "/Android/data/com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad/recorded files.txt", recordedFilesArray.get(toDelete), input.getText().toString());
                            currentFilePath = externalStoragePath + File.separator + "/Android/data/com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad/" + recordedFilesArray.get(toDelete) + ".mp3";
                            renameFile(input.getText().toString());
                            recordedFilesArray.set(toDelete, input.getText().toString());
                            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    renameAlert.show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

This works fine, the item name and everything else is successfully changed, but it only works ONCE. When I rename the file and then try to rename anything again, the app crashes and this is the logcat file:

```
08-21 11:26:13.631: E/AndroidRuntime(7260): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 11:26:13.631: E/AndroidRuntime(7260): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
08-21 11:26:13.631: E/AndroidRuntime(7260):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3506)
08-21 11:26:13.631: E/AndroidRuntime(7260):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3377)
08-21 11:26:13.631: E/AndroidRuntime(7260):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3353)
08-21 11:26:13.631: E/AndroidRuntime(7260):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.setupView(AlertController.java:413)
08-21 11:26:13.631: E/AndroidRuntime(7260):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:241)
08-21 11:26:13.631: E/AndroidRuntime(7260):     at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:337)
08-21 11:26:13.631: E/AndroidRuntime(7260):     at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:355)
08-21 11:26:13.631: E/AndroidRuntime(7260):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:260)
08-21 11:26:13.631: E/AndroidRuntime(7260):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:951)
08-21 11:26:13.631: E/AndroidRuntime(7260):     at com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad.RecordedLibrary$3$2.onClick(RecordedLibrary.java:158)
08-21 11:26:13.631: E/AndroidRuntime(7260):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
08-21 11:26:13.631: E/AndroidRuntime(7260):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-21 11:26:13.631: E/AndroidRuntime(7260):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-21 11:26:13.631: E/AndroidRuntime(7260):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-21 11:26:13.631: E/AndroidRuntime(7260):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 11:26:13.631: E/AndroidRuntime(7260):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-21 11:26:13.631: E/AndroidRuntime(7260):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-21 11:26:13.631: E/AndroidRuntime(7260):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-21 11:26:13.631: E/AndroidRuntime(7260):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is input in `renameAlert.setView(input);`?

Comment: Did you `dismiss` the `renameAlert`?

Comment: need more code..to understand 'input' in setView(input)

Comment: First: Try reinstantiating renameAlert as in renameAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

Comment: @Cruceo Yes, that was the problem, I only declared renameAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext); one time in onCreate and then never again. Thank you! Feel free to post it as an answer so that I can accept it :) sorry for the late reply by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user [Cruceo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1426565/cruceo) gave me an answer in the comments. The problem was that I declared a new AlertDialog.Builder in onCreate so it was created only the first time activity was started. So I just moved

```
renameAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
```

to the click method so that it was declared everytime the button was clicked and it worked.

Cruceo: if you post your own answer I will accept your. Thank you!